# Comparing 2 excel files to extract rows based on a reference number in one file and copy them to a new file

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 excel files.
File 1 is my master file and has the master transaction data with a unique transaction reference number in the second column.
File 2 contains raw transaction data which includes a transaction reference number. However in file 2 there maybe 2 rows with same transaction column.

I would like to use Python to compare the rows in File 2 with File 1 using the transaction reference number. If the transaction reference number from file 2 is present in file 1 it should do nothing. However, if the transaction reference number from file 2 is NOT present in File 1 the entire row from file 2 containing the transaction reference number should be copied into a new excel file - File 3

I am just starting to learn Python and am unable to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
"""
author: gorgie7
"""

#import thes 2 packages
import xlwings as xw
import xlsxwriter as ex

#create the third file where the not equals get stored
newFile = ex.Workbook("File3.xlsx") 
newSheet = newFile.add_worksheet()

#open file 1
ws_1 = xw.Book("File1.xlsx").sheets["Sheet1"]
#create Array for the saved items
chekArr = []

#run first file
#in range you can change the rows
for cell in range(1, 3):
    #you can replace "A" with the colum you want
    item = ws_1.range("A"+str(cell)).value
    print(item)
    chekArr.append(item)

#open file 2
ws_2 = xw.Book("File2.xlsx").sheets["Sheet1"]

#run second file              
for cell in range(1,3):
    #same thing like above
    item = ws_2.range("A"+str(cell)).value
    #chek if item is equal to file 1
    if item == chekArr[cell-1]:
        continue
    else:
        #writing in file 3
        #just replace "A" and "b" with the colums you want
        zell_1 = "A" + str(cell)
        zell_2 = "B" + str(cell)
        newSheet.write(zell_1,item)
        newSheet.write(zell_2, chekArr[cell-1])

#closing File 3 important      
newFile.close()
```

Note: if you havent installed the two packages type:

```
pip install xlwings
pip install xlsxwriter
```

in command Prompt